# -[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance error with a NSMutableArray with Images

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsmutablearray, uiimagepickercontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I have a storyboard app which has a `UIViewController` and a `UICollectionViewController`. In the view controller, the user chooses multiple photos from the iPhone's photo library (Since there is no API for multi-select in iOS, I used [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController) to achieve this). And it segues to the collection view controller where the selected photos should be shown in little image views.

The image library shows up and I am able to select multiple photos. But when it segues to the collection view controller, it throws the **-[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance** error in the collection view's `cellForItemAtIndexPath` event.

Below is the code I have so far.

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ELCImagePickerController.h"
#import "ELCAlbumPickerController.h"
#import "ELCAssetTablePicker.h"
#import "GalleryViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *cameraImages;

- (IBAction)chooseImages:(id)sender;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)chooseImages:(id)sender
{
    UIActionSheet *photoSourcePicker = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                                   delegate:self
                                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                     destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Take Photo", @"Choose from Library", nil, nil];
    [photoSourcePicker showInView:self.view];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
                ELCAlbumPickerController *albumController = [[ELCAlbumPickerController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
                ELCImagePickerController *elcPicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] initWithRootViewController:albumController];
                albumController.parent = elcPicker;
                elcPicker.delegate = self;

                if ([self.view respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]){
                    [self presentViewController:elcPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
                } else {
                    [self presentViewController:elcPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
                }
            }
            else {
                UIAlertView *alert;
                alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                   message:@"This device doesn't have a camera"
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
            }
            break;

        case 1:
            if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
                ELCAlbumPickerController *albumController = [[ELCAlbumPickerController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
                ELCImagePickerController *elcPicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] initWithRootViewController:albumController];
                albumController.parent = elcPicker;
                elcPicker.delegate = self;

                if ([self.view respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]){
                    [self presentViewController:elcPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
                } else {
                    [self presentViewController:elcPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
                }
            }
            else {
                UIAlertView *alert;
                alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                   message:@"This device doesn't support photo libraries"
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
            }
            break;
    }
}

- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    self.cameraImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:info.count];


    for (NSDictionary *camImage in info) {
        UIImage *image = [camImage objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        [self.cameraImages addObject:image];
    }
    /*
     for (UIImage *image in info) {
     [self.attachImages addObject:image];
     }
     */

    NSLog(@"number of images = %d", self.cameraImages.count);
    if (self.cameraImages.count > 0) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toGallery" sender:nil];
    }
}


- (void)elcImagePickerControllerDidCancel:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)]) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toGallery"]) {
        GalleryViewController *galleryVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        galleryVC.selectedImages = self.cameraImages;
    }
}

@end
```

**GalleryViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ELCImagePickerController.h"
#import "ELCAlbumPickerController.h"
#import "ELCAssetTablePicker.h"
#import "ImageCell.h"

@interface GalleryViewController : UICollectionViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *selectedImages;

@end
```

**GalleryViewController.m**

```
#import "GalleryViewController.h"

@interface GalleryViewController ()

@end

@implementation GalleryViewController


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.selectedImages.count;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ImageCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"imgCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *image;
    int row = indexPath.row;

    image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.selectedImages[row]]; //This is where it throws the error
    cell.imageView.image = image;

    return cell;
}

@end
```

To further demonstrate the issue, I've slapped together a demo project which you can download from [here](http://www20.zippyshare.com/v/63804660/file.html).

I know thus question has been asked many time before here on SO. I tried them all but to no avail prior to posting my question here.

I'd appreciate if someone can tell me how to get rid of this error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hey I understood your problem you are already having an array of images, why using imageNamed: constructor again.

```
image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.selectedImages[row]];
cell.imageView.image = image;
//This throws a exception because, you have UIImage objects in your array and here imageNamed: takes NSString as an argument , so you are trying to pass a UIImage object instead of a NSString object
```

Directly take out image from array and assign like this:

```
cell.imageView.image = (UIImage*) [self.selectedImages objectAtIndex:row];
```

UIImage * is probably not needed.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I'm working on iOS at work. I'll have to check it once I go back there tomorrow morning. I'll reply back with my results. :)

Comment: Hi satheeshwaran, I just checked it out and it works perfectly! Thanks a lot. I followed a tutorial on how to do this and there it was shown like this. That's why I added another array. Anyway thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

`self.selectedImages[row]` should be a `NSString`. It seems like it is a `UIImage` instead of an `NSString`. Its trying to call length method on the `UIImage` instance.