# Video thumbnail does not appear in collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uicollectionview, nsarray

```
self.url = [self grabFileURL:@"video.mov"];
NSLog(@"The URL is: %@", self.url);

AVURLAsset *asset1 = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:self.url options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generate1 = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset1];
generate1.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
NSError *err = NULL;
CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 2);
CGImageRef oneRef = [generate1 copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
UIImage *one = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:oneRef];

CaptureViewController *cv = [[CaptureViewController alloc]init];
[cv.thumbnail setImage:one];

NSLog(@"The thumbnail is: %@", one);

one = [UIImage imageNamed:@"vid.png"];

videoGallery = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"vid.png", nil];
```

Edit:

```
- (NSURL*)grabFileURL:(NSString *)fileName {

// find Documents directory
NSURL *documentsURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];

// append a file name to it
documentsURL = [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

return documentsURL;
}
```

No output error in NSLog but the thumbnail still doesn't show up in collection view controller. What have I missed ?

Comment: Can you show the `grabFileURL:`?

Comment: Question has been edited. Kindly see above

Comment: Why do you change your 'one' UIImage after setting cv.thumbnail ? What happens when you delete 'one = [UIImage imageNamed:@"vid.png"];' ?

Comment: If I delete that code, i will get this error **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x176bcdf0'**

Comment: Got the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060840/uiimage-length-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error-with-a-nsmutable

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)generateImageForImageView:(UIImageView *) imageView withURL:(NSString *) VideoURL
{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:VideoURL];

    AVURLAsset *asset1 = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generate1 = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]     initWithAsset:asset1];
    generate1.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
    NSError *err = NULL;
    CMTime time = [asset1 duration];
    time.value = 0;
    CGImageRef oneRef = [generate1 copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
    UIImage *one = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:oneRef];
    [imageView setImage:one];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
}
```

use this method hope it will be useful to you, its work for me

Comment: Thanks but I know how to generate thumbnails. The issue is that the thumbnail does not appear on a collection view controller when assigned to NSArray

Comment: can you show the code which you are used to assign image

Comment: one = [UIImage imageNamed:@"vid.png"];